# If $m = 6x + 5$, what equation is equivalent to $(6x + 5)^2 - 10=-18x - 15$ in terms of $m$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, substitution

This question I am asking right now comes from the Khan Academy practice task entitled 'Solve quadratic equations by using structure', so the credit goes to them.

So, if $m = 6x + 5$, then what equation is equivalent to $(6x + 5)^2 - 10 = -18x - 15$ in terms of $m$? I have been thumping my head on this, but it just doesn't seem to get me anywhere. Can anyone help me? Until then, I'll be attempting to solve the problem and look for answers.

By the way, the answer is supposed to be in the form of: $$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$$

Comment: It is $m^2-10=-3m$ (replace $6x+5$ by $m$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal is to replace all the $x$'s with $m$'s.

This equation is quite convenient as it is for replacement. As @ASKASK noted in his answer, the right side can be rewritten as $-3m$.

The left side falls exactly as you would expect it to. Because $m = 6x + 5$, you can just rewrite the left side as $m^2-10$. (Note: $(6x-5)^2 = m^2$).

At this point, you should have an equation with $m$'s on both sides. You'll probably want to rearrange and factor it to solve for $m$.

But that's another question.

Comment: if you want to emphasize the character in $\LaTeX$, instead of using * outside of $\LaTeX$, I recommend using \boldsymbol{m} ($\boldsymbol{m}$)

Comment: You can also use colors with \color{red}{m} ($\color{red}{m}$), for example.

Comment: I think he/she is trying to use `*` symbols to produce "home-made" italics, which clearly should be replaced by $\LaTeX$ complete formulas.

Comment: @JnxF Oh, I see what you mean.

Comment: @GBeau I have proposed an edit in order to improve the formatting (and to settle our headache).

Comment: Thanks for the help; still getting used to LaTEX.

Comment: @KaR1367, you might find useful this post. It includes several $\LaTeX$ writing tips that can help you in order to improve your use of $\LaTeX$ utilities (in this web, MathJax). http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @JnxF Thanks, will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$-18x-15=-3(6x+5)=-3m$$

Comment: I don't get what the hint is trying to take away. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue $-18x-15=-3(\color{red}{6x+5})=-3\color{red}{m}$

Comment: I rewrote the right hand side of the equation in terms of $m$. Now see if you can rewrite the left hand side in terms of $m$ and you'll be all done

Comment: From ASKASK answer you can easily see that your expression is equivalent to $m^2 - 10 = - 3m$, which is an equation only in terms of $m$.

Comment: Oh, oh, oh, KaR1367 just gave me the answer; the left-hand side is rewritten as $m^2 - 10$. So, I have $m^2 - 10 = -3m$. When I get the $-3m$ on the left-hand side, I get $m^2 + 3m - 10 = 0$! I found my answer!

Comment: So, this can apply anywhere, like in this equation: If $p = 3x + 4$, then what equation is equivalent to $(3x + 4)^2 - 36 = 15x + 20$ in terms of $p$? Since $15x + 20$ is equal to $5(3x + 4)$, which in terms of $p$ is (the whole equation) is $p^2 - 36 = 5p$. When you bring $5p$ onto the left hand side, you get $p^2 - 5p - 36 = 0$! See, it works anywhere! Thank you guys!